# Unexpected jQuery ajax json response

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I am having some strange issues with jQuery (1.7.2) ajax and asp.net.

When using the code below locally this all appears to work fine.  The ajax fires fine, the modal pops up as expected, the div slides down, and I'm very happy with the result.

However, on our development server, we run into some strange issues.  We start hitting the error function.  In the error function, the return text isn't our JSON'd time stamp, but rather the HTML from a different page in our page flow.  We've tried playing with the params to .ajax, we've tried fiddling with the modal, we've tried just returning the timestamp in our code behind method, we tried changing our dataType to text.  That allowed it to fire the modal, however, Inf.innerHTML just ended up displaying the rendering of that other page in our page flow.

We've spent a bunch of time trying to debug this, but we're still stuck.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

jQuery:

```
$("#<%= Btn.ClientID %>").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                type: "POST",
                url: "Page.aspx/Method",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#Modal").modal({
                        closeClass: "Modal-Close",
                        escClose: false,
                        opacity: 35,
                        overlayCss: { backgroundColor: "#000" }
                    }); //end Modal
                    //timeStamp = data.d; //Timestamp elsewhere in the js
                }, //end success
                error: function(xhr, status, error) { alert("xhr: " + xhr.responseText + "\n\nstatus: " + status + "\n\nerror: " + error); }
            }); //end ajax
            return false;
        }); //end Btn.click

$(".Modal-Close").click(function() {
       ModalClose();
});

var timeStamp;

    function ModalClose() {
        var img = document.getElementById("imgP");
        var Inf = document.getElementById("Info");
        var Name = document.getElementById("<%=divName.ClientID %>").value;
        img.src = "difImg.png";
        Inf.innerHTML = "Sometext" + Name + ", MoreText.<br />" + timeStamp;
        var divO = document.getElementById("<%=divOut.ClientID %>");
        $(divO).slideDown();
    }
```

C# Page Code-behind

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string Method()
{
    // Various magic
    return "{\"d\":\"" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt") + "\"}";
}
```

Comment: first thing i would do is run it in chrome and look at the network trace page to see exactly whats going on the wire,

Comment: At very first sight "// Various magic" seems to be throwing an error, it would be good to add a try / catch and log the exception if any

Comment: @pm100 Looks like it's doing some odd redirects in the background, but we can't really figure out why these are happening.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi The various magic is commented out until this problem can be solved.  We are trying to reduce the number of possible contributing factors to these redirections.

Comment: redirects to where? FormsAuth perhaps, that does redirects

Comment: It's redirecting to the first page in our flow.  So the .ajax() call is returning the first page in the flow's html.  We do have some url params, could that be causing an issue?

Comment: try calling the page explicitly and see if you get the json in the response back through chromes dev tools